# Using NoSQL/MongoDB in Visual Studio Express or Professional

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio, nosql

Our company is planning on purchasing a copy of Visual Studio Professional 2013 for some features that are absent from the Express edition, mainly, the ability to create installers, plugin functionality, and likely the ability to use NoSQL databases. We only plan on buying one copy as our budget is tight, where the rest of the developers when not needing to use the Professional features can use the Express edition.

I know that Express has a database explorer, so that still allows basic SQL functionality, but we are interested in exploring object-oriented databases, mainly MongoDB or other NoSQL databases. My question is - can you use MongoDB (or other object-based databases) with the Express edition, or does it require the Professional edition?

From my research so far, MongoDB compiles to 32-bit and 64-bit, but because VSE can only do 32-bit builds, there will be issues with using it in VS Express.

Next, `if` the Professional edition is necessary to work with MongoDB, would we then be able to open solutions/projects created with the Professional edition in Express?

Thank you.

Comment: `the ability to create executables` - What? since when does VS Express  not allow you to create Windows `.exe`s?

Comment: Sorry, wrong word. I meant installer.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to use MongoDB for queries, updates or inserts, the answer is yes, you can use Visual Studio Express.

You only need the  [MongoDB C# driver](http://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/) in your project and configure the connection to the database. But it is the same with Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL or whatever database you want. You don't need a Pro version of VS.

If you mean that you want to develop a plugin for explore MongoDB databases, then you need  VS Professional or better, or use an external tool.

Comment: Hi ruben. What is the difference between using queries, updates, or inserts, versus developing a plugin to explore MongoDB databases? You need VS Pro to develop a plugin because Express doesn't support plugins, is that right? My last question has to do with compatibility - say I develop a plugin for MongoDB, I wouldn't be able to open it in Express right?

Comment: Yes. You can not add plugins to VS Express Edition.

I have never developed a plugin, but I guess that you have to use MongoDB C# driver in the same way you would use for web or desktop applications.

Comment: I have forgotten to answer one of your questions. You can not develop a plugin with VS Express. You need VS SDK and one of the requeriments is VS Pro or higher. You have more info [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668)